# How does Parent works in System.Windows.Forms

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have following code which is ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258282/powershell-ignores-add-type-unless-it-is-copied-and-pasted-directly-to-console)) working as expected:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    MyForm($mystuff) {
        #Do-Stuff
        $this.Add_Load( $this.MyForm_Load )
    }

    $MyForm_Load = {
        $mlabel = [System.Windows.Forms.Label]::new()
            $mlabel.Name = "label"
            $mlabel.Text = "disabled"

        $mbutton = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]::new()
            $mbutton.Name = "button"
            $mbutton.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(100,100)
            $mbutton.Add_Click( $this.mbutton_click )

        $this.Controls.Add($mlabel)
        $this.Controls.Add($mbutton)

    # ----------------------------------------------
    # Now $this.controls has something. We can now access it.
    # ----------------------------------------------
        if ($this.controls["label"].text -eq "enabled"){
            $mbutton.text = "disable"
        }else{
            $mbutton.text = "enable"
        }
    }

    $mbutton_click = {
        if ($this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text -eq "enabled"){
            $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "disabled"
            $this.Parent.Controls["button"].Text = "enable"
        }
        else{
            $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "enabled"
            $this.Parent.Controls["button"].Text = "disable"
        }
    }
}

$foo = [MyForm]::new("test")
$foo.ShowDialog()
```

but when I replace following section:

```
$mbutton_click = {
    if ($this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text -eq "enabled"){
        $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "disabled"
        $this.Parent.Controls["button"].Text = "enable"
    }
    else{
        $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "enabled"
        $this.Parent.Controls["button"].Text = "disable"
    }
}
```

For this (missing `Parent`):

```
$mbutton_click = {
    if ($this.Controls["label"].Text -eq "enabled"){
        $this.Controls["label"].Text = "disabled"
        $this.Controls["button"].Text = "enable"
    }
    else{
        $this.Controls["label"].Text = "enabled"
        $this.Controls["button"].Text = "disable"
    }
}
```

Then my script stops working and I see following error on console:

```
The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

Why`$MyForm_Load` works without `Parent` but `$mbutton_click` requires `Parent`? Isn't both `$MyForm_Load` and `$mbutton_click` part of same object? How does `Parent` works in `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: Inside the `$mbutton_click`, the variable `$this` refers to the button itself. Since the button is placed directly on the form, you need to use `.Parent` to reference the form (and its oter controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mhu says, it's because one is bound to the Form Load **event** vs an individual control **object**.

A Form is a class. That means a Form has:

**Properties**

Properties are **objects** in the class that can be referenced. They can be simple strings like `.Name`, or complex like `.Controls` which return a complex  `Control.ControlCollection` object.

**Methods:**

Calling a method calls a **single** function definition that is fully defined at compile time. Calling a method e.g. `MyForm.ShowDialog()` calls that individual `.ShowDialog()` function.

**Events:**

Sometimes we want to do something, but we can't fully define the method call at compile time. But, at the same time, we really like the convenience of calling something that is defined like a method. This is where Event's can be used.

First. We think of a method call for something useful that we want to happen, like `MyForm.Load()`, and that's all we have to define at compile time. Right now we don't know what we want to do. We know that we want to be able to load a form, but we don't know what it will do or look like. So we put this in as a placeholder that we can call.

After some thought, we figure out what we want to do, and how we want things to look like and we build a function that does something useful. We then subscribe this function to an Event. This is like connecting it.

In the first case:

```
MyForm($mystuff) {
    $this.Add_Load( $this.MyForm_Load )
}
```

We are registering `MyForm_Load` to the `MyForm.Load` **event**:

```
MyForm.Load -> MyForm_Load
```

This means that when we call `MyForm.Load()` it will call the connected function `MyForm_Load` that we wrote, and will execute it as if we wrote it as a real method at compile time.

Therefore inside `MyForm_Load`, `$this` refers to the `MyForm` Form object. i.e. No `.parent` needed, because you **are** the form.

Therefore to access the `MyForm.Controls` property, you can access it directly.

```
MyForm.Load -> MyForm_Load
MyForm.Controls
```

The second:

```
$MyForm_Load = {
    $mlabel = [System.Windows.Forms.Label]::new()
        $mlabel.Name = "label"
        $mlabel.Text = "disabled"

    $mbutton = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]::new()
        $mbutton.Name = "button"
        $mbutton.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(100,100)
        $mbutton.Add_Click( $this.mbutton_click )

    $this.Controls.Add($mlabel)
    $this.Controls.Add($mbutton)
}
```

Adds `Controls` to the `Form.Controls` object:

```
MyForm.Load -> MyForm_Load
MyForm.Controls 
           |-> mlabel  
           |-> mbutton
```

The `mbutton` control has a click event attached:

```
$MyForm_Load = {
...
    $mbutton.Add_Click( $this.mbutton_click )
...
}

$mbutton_click = {
...
        $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "disabled"
...
}
```

So it now looks like:

```
MyForm.Load -> MyForm_Load
MyForm.Controls
           |-> mlabel.Text
           |-> mbutton.Click -> mbutton_click
```

So to go from `MyForm_Load` to `mlabel.Text` is:

```
 $this  .Controls["label"] .Text 
(MyForm).Controls[(mlabel)].Text
```

Whereas from `mbutton_click`, the `mbutton` doesn't have any controls inside it. You have to go "up" a level to the form to get the `mlabel` control:

```
 $this   .Parent  .Controls["label"] .Text 
(mbutton).(MyForm).Controls[(mlabel)].Text
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the event handler `$this` is bound to the sender of the event (the button in this case) instead of your class instance. So something like this should also work:

```
$mbutton_click = {
    if ($this.Text -ne "enable") {
        $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "disabled"
        $this.Text = "enable"
    }
    else{
        $this.Parent.Controls["label"].Text = "enabled"
        $this.Text = "disable"
    }
}
```